# Blackberry Accelerometer data for Rotation

Tags: blackberry, accelerometer

I understand the x/y/z G-force values and the "orientation" data [available for Blackberry programs](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/AccelerometerSensor.html).

My question is how can I extract rotation/orientation RAW-DATA? (Such as is used by the programmer for [the "Blackberry-Spirit-Level" app](http://www.mobileindustryreview.com/2009/01/turn_a_blackberry_storm_into_a_spirit_level.html))

The "Orientation" API seems to return constants like `ORIENTATION_TOP_UP` and `ORIENTATION_RIGHT_UP` rather than some degree float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a direct way to get the device orientation angles, but you can calculate them with the raw data available via the `AccelerometerSensor` class you mentioned.

Looking at the [example they show in the API docs](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/AccelerometerSensor.html), you can get the raw X, Y, and Z acceleration data.  You then use trigonometry to figure out what the angle is.  For example, a device held with its Z-axis pointing straight down (and not moving ... or accelerating relative to the earth), would give a Z acceleration value equal to **G**, [the acceleration due to Gravity](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/AccelerometerSensor.html#G_FORCE_VALUE).

If the device is held at some *other* angle, the acceleration value along that axis will be reduced by the *sine/cosine* of the angle between the axis, and a vertical line towards the earth.

This sample code shows how you can get some of those angles:

```java
public void run()
{
    // open channel
    Channel rawDataChannel = AccelerometerSensor.openRawDataChannel( Application.getApplication() );
    // create raw sample vector with three components - X, Y, Z
    short[] xyz = new short[ 3 ];
    while( isRunning() ) {
        // read acceleration
        rawDataChannel.getLastAccelerationData( xyz );
        // process the acceleration
        process( xyz );
        // sleep for maintaining query rate
        try {
            Thread.sleep( 500 );
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    // close the channel to stop sensor query routine
    rawDataChannel.close();
}

private void process(short[] xyz) {

    short X = xyz[0];
    short Y = xyz[1];
    short Z = xyz[2];

    final double roll = MathUtilities.atan2(X, Z) * 180.0 / Math.PI;
    final double pitch = MathUtilities.atan2(Y, Math.sqrt(X*X + Z*Z)) * 180.0 / Math.PI;
    final double tilt = MathUtilities.acos(Z / Math.sqrt(X*X + Y*Y + Z*Z)) * 180.0 / Math.PI;

    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            String output = "Angles are {" + roll + ", " + pitch + ", " + tilt + "}";
            textField.setText(output);
        }
    });
}
```

For a reference of what is meant by *roll*, *pitch*, and *tilt*, see [this document](http://www.freescale.com/files/sensors/doc/app_note/AN3461.pdf).  That's where the math came from.

### Other Issues

This is not from a production app that I've written, so the code has not been thoroughly tested.  The sign of the angles might be wrong, there might be instabilities in the equations, or other things like that.

Also, if you're using **raw** accelerometer data, you will need to implement a calibration function.  If you run any kind of smartphone level app, you'll see an example of how that's done.  So, the results calculated above will need to be adjusted by your calibration constants.

Finally, raw accelerometer data can be noisy, so you may need to filter/smooth the data, too, depending on how you want to use it.

This is just meant to be a starting point.  Good luck!

Comment: That sounds like what I'm looking for. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user386093, if the answer works for you, please remember to **accept** it as a solution, by clicking the little checkmark to the left of the answer.  Thanks.